# Checking android emulator is Silent or not

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, ringtone

I am developing an android application for which i want to know whether the android phone is silent or not. I need to know how can I check this thing on android emulator by Java Code. Also how I could know the same thing without any code just by graphical interface of android emulator

Answer (score 1):

You can check by the following line fo code.

```
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    if (audioManager.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
        // If it reaches here then it means it is silent mode
    }
```

Hope this will help you.